# i need to match the values of columns

Tags: awk

I have two files in each file i have tow columns ,i need to match the first value of column two of file1 with each value from column two of file2 if they are equal i need to subtract the value of the matched value of column one from each other, after that i need to combine column one from the two files in one file but the two columns should be adjacent to each other
if the two vales do not matched do nothing

file1

```
344  0
465  1
729  2
777  3
676  4
862  5
```

file2

```
766  0
937  1
980  2
237  3
736  5
```

example

```
422
208
251
```

Comment: there are 5 matches (0,1,2,3,5) but why the final output has only 3 lines?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how you come up with your given output. This might help you:

```
$ join -j 2 file1 file2
0 344 766
1 465 937
2 729 980
3 777 237
5 862 736
```

But where you go from there, you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on @glenn jackman's answer... perhaps this:

```
join -j 2 file1 file2 | awk '{if ($3>$2) print $3-$2; else print $2-$3}'
```

That will print the absolute difference between the two column 1's when there is a match in the column 2's. But it doesn't match your expected output, which, aside from the first value, doesn't seem to have an obvious relation to your inputs in any way that seems to match your question...

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help:

```
awk '
BEGIN { printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","File1","File2","Difference(f2-f1)" }
NR==FNR { a[$2]=$1; next }
{ printf "%d\t%d\t%d\n",a[$2],$1,$1-a[$2] }' file1 file2
```

#### Output:

```
File1   File2   Difference(f2-f1)
344     766      422
465     937      472
729     980      251
777     237     -540
862     736     -126
```